# Is there an elegant way to test if one instance method is an alias for another?

Tags: ruby, reflection, alias-method

In a unit test I need to test whether alias methods defined by alias_method have been properly defined. I could simply use the same tests on the aliases used for their originals, but I'm wondering whether there's a more definitive or efficient solution. For instance, is there a way to 1) dereference a method alias and return its original's name, 2) get and compare some kind of underlying method identifier or address, or 3) get and compare method definitions? For example:

```
class MyClass
  def foo
    # do something
  end

  alias_method :bar, :foo
end

describe MyClass do
  it "method bar should be an alias for method foo" do
    m = MyClass.new
    # ??? identity(m.bar).should == identity(m.foo) ???
  end
end
```

Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to identify aliased methods in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676834/is-it-possible-to-identify-aliased-methods-in-ruby)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Method.html),

> Two method objects are equal if they
> are bound to the same object and
> contain the same body.

Calling [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000610) and comparing the `Method` objects that it returns will verify that the methods are equivalent:

```
m.method(:bar) == m.method(:foo)
```

Comment: I was sure I remembered that this didn't work, but I just tried it to confirm and it works consistently in Ruby 1.8, 1.9 and MacRuby. But I still don't see it in RubySpec, so it very likely won't work on an unrelated implementation.

Comment: Also, in general, methods that merely have identical bodies but aren't copied one from the other are emphatically *not* equal. Proof: `Class.new{def foo() end; def bar() end; puts instance_method(:foo)==instance_method(:bar)}`

Comment: @Chuck: Thanks for pointing that out. I should have tried it.

Comment: Also, "returns true on aliased methods" from http://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/method/equal_value_spec.rb + http://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/method/shared/eql.rb seems to cover `m.method(:bar) == m.method(:foo)` when one is an alias of the other.

Answer (score 3):

bk1e's method works most of the time, but I just happened to hit the case where it doesn't work:

```
class Stream
  class << self
    alias_method :open, :new
  end
end

open = Stream.method(:open)
new = Stream.method(:new)
p open, new                   # => #<Method: Stream.new>, #<Method: Class#new>
p open.receiver, new.receiver # => Stream, Stream
p open == new                 # => false
```

The output is produced in Ruby 1.9, not sure if it's a bug or not since Ruby 1.8 produces `true` for the last line. So, if you are using 1.9, be careful if you are aliasing an inherited class method (like Class#new), These two methods are bound to the same object (the class object `Stream`), but they are considered not equivalent by Ruby 1.9.

My workaround is simple - alias the original method again and test the equality of the two aliases:

```
class << Stream; alias_method :alias_test_open, :new; end
open = Stream.method(:open)
alias_test_open = Stream.method(:alias_test_open)
p open, alias_test_open                   # => #<Method: Stream.new>, #<Method: Stream.new>
p open.receiver, alias_test_open.receiver # => Stream, Stream
p open == alias_test_open                 # => true
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

See http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7613

So `Method#==` should return false in this case since a `super` call would invoke different methods; it is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `MyClass.instance_method(:foo)` will result [UnboundMethod](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/UnboundMethod.html) instance, which has `eql?` method.

So the answer is:

```
describe MyClass do
  subject { described_class }

  specify do
    expect(subject.instance_method(:foo)).to be_eql(subject.instance_method(:bar))
  end
end
```