# List of Ruby Class Method Aliases

Tags: ruby

The Random class method `Random.rand` is aliased as `rand` (i.e. equivalent to `Random.rand`). Is there anyway to get a listing of the class method aliases used by Ruby?

Not sure that Ruby documentation offers a complete list as it does identify `rand` as an alias of `Random.rand` but there is no mention that `srand` is an alias yet it can be invoked using `srand` or `Random.srand`

I eventually answered my own question - please have a look below.

Comment: `srand` is not an alias for rand; it's used to seed the pseudorandom number generator to "[ensure repeatable sequences of random numbers between different runs of the program](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)". As for your question, I suggest you read this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676834/is-it-possible-to-identify-aliased-methods-in-ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676834/is-it-possible-to-identify-aliased-methods-in-ruby)

Comment: In reply to you statement that "srand is not an alias for rand;" - I'm not sure why you thought I was implying it was. What I wrote was "… but there is no mention that srand is an alias yet it can be invoked by either using srand or Random.srand"

As far as the referred link, it is useful if you want to determine instance method aliases, however, I was trying to get a list of class method aliases.  Please see my edit to original post for details as my confusion re class method aliases and how I now believe those so called aliases are instead Kernel instance methods.

Comment: I see; sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Edit to My Original Question:

This question had its root in a misunderstanding of the Ruby Random class documentation reference http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Random.html that refers to an alias rand for the Random.rand class method. It turns out that rand and srand invoke the Kernel instance methods. To invoke the Random class class methods, rand and srand, you need to give the full resolved invocation e.g. Random.rand or Random.srand

As such, the list I was looking for is actually the Kernel documentation of the Kernel's instance methods http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html