# ruby undefine aliases when undefining method

Tags: ruby

I noticed in Ruby when you undefine a method, it does NOT undefine aliases:

```
class Foo
end

Foo.instance_eval do
  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => bar

Foo.instance_eval {alias :baar :bar }

Foo.instance_eval { undef :bar }

Foo.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class

Foo.baar # => bar
```

What is the correct approach to undefine all aliases associated with a method when that method is deleted via undef?

Comment: The second `Foo.bar` works for me, are you missing an `undef` in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all methods aliased to a specific method by selecting all methods equal to it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676834/is-it-possible-to-identify-aliased-methods-in-ruby)), so you could define a method like this:

```
class Class
  def undef_with_aliases(method_name)
    methods.select { |m| method(m) == method(method_name) }.each { |m| instance_eval "undef #{m}" }
  end
end

Foo.instance_eval { undef_with_aliases :bar }    

Foo.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class

Foo.baar # => NoMethodError: undefined method `baar' for Foo:Class
```