# How can I obtain the aliases of of a method?

Tags: ruby, methods

Given a module/class and the name of an instance method defined on it, how can I obtain all the aliases of the method?

Comment: I can think of a brute force way to do it, but I am wondering if there is a better way. If no good answer is posted, then I will post mine.

Comment: Is it something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3677258/163640 ?

Comment: @eugen That is close to what I had in mind. And the accepted answer is a very good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if iterating over all instance methods is considered "brute force", but this would work:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end

  alias bar2 bar
  alias_method :bar3, :bar
end

Foo.instance_methods.select do |m|
  Foo.instance_method(m) == Foo.instance_method(:bar)
end
#=> [:bar, :bar2, :bar3]
```

Comment: I had something similar. The reason I think it is brute force is because I would have to check for instance methods as well as private instance methods and create huge arrays each time. But I guess this is the best way to do it.